# The number of solutions of equation $2\cos^2x-5\cos x=0$ from $x\in [0,4\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

This is a simplified which version of a very large equation given which is

$$\cos 2x-3\cos x + 1=\frac{1}{(\cot 2x-\cot x).\sin (x-\pi)}$$

I have solved the equation to get the simplification given. It is clear that
$$\cos x \not = \frac 52$$ but $$\cos x =0$$ there are 4 values in $[0,4\pi]$ which satisfy this, but the answer says no solution. It even has an explanation, but I couldn’t understand it well. What’s the reason?

Comment: Is the equation in the equation body equivalent to that in the title?

Comment: Well , [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos+2x-3cos+x+%2B+1%3D1%2F%28%28cot+2x-cot+x%29sin+%28x-pi%29%29) agrees with you. But for $\cos x = 0$ , $\cot 2x$ is not defined and so it is an extraneous solution.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch it is

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit that explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Write your equation in the form
$$\cos(x)(2\cos(x)-5)=0$$